# Is it possible to get the path of a bat file that invokes an application?

Tags: delphi, console-application

For example my console application is here:

> C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Console App Test\Win32\Debug\ConsoleAppTest.exe

I have a bat file at `C:\Temp\exec.bat' that will invoke the console application:

Content of bat file:

> "C:\Users\User\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Console App Test\Win32\Debug\ConsoleAppTest.exe"

With Delphi, in the console application, is it possible for me to "know" that the console application was started by `C:\Temp\exec.bat`? More specifically, from the path `C:\Temp`?

Comment: No. Why do you need that anyway?

Comment: I want to save error logs in the `C:\Temp` folder, not in the console app folder...

Comment: Isn't `C:\Temp` the current directory when the app is started from the bat file?

Comment: That would be the answer to my question then... use `GetCurrentDir`

Comment: If you create a file without specifiyng a directory, it is created in the current directory. You don't even need to call `GetCurrentDir`.

Comment: That is also a useful piece of information...

Comment: Don't forget that when starting with `c:\temp\exec.bat` the current directory may be anything else, even drive maybe different.

Comment: @fpiette: What do you mean? Won't it always be `C:\Temp`?

Comment: It depends how the bat is started. If you double-click on it in an Explorer window, it will always be `C:\Temp`. If you start it from a shortcut, the current directory can be specified in the shortcurt properties (but will be `C:\Temp` by default).

Comment: No, it won't be - necessarily - "C:\Temp" if you run the bat with a full path like `C:\Temp\exec.bat`. That's what I said in my previous comment. You can easily try that by yourself using different ways to start the bat file. Try this: launch command prompt, change dir to anything else than C:\Temp, run exec.bat by typing c:\temp\exec.bat.

Comment: @fpiette: I c. That's why I was asking my question, because current dir can be variable, so it would be more reliable to get the "caller of the application". However, for my purposes `GetCurrentDir` will be sufficient, because I am going to click in Explorer window...

Comment: By the way, saving logs in the current directory when the app is started is REALLY a bad idea.

Comment: Actually it is not to save logs, however @Olivier had trouble imagining why I would need such a function, so I gave an example..

Comment: A well behaved application should save the logs either in the user profile, for example in the AppData\Local folder (Private to each user), or in ProgramData folder (Accessible for all users). In those directories, you should create a subdir with your company name and then a sub-subdir with the application name and there you save your logs. Do **not** hardcode those paths but query the shell to get it. Use `SHGetFolderPath`.

Comment: You should **never** give false informations (here saving logs)! You'll get bad answers.

Comment: Sheeww... I thought we could relax a bit in the comments? Anyway, I had 2 reasons, the lesser one was to save logs in that location, the main one, was longer to describe

Comment: @RaelB So your question title lead you to a track you should not engage in. You should open a new question when you'll have tried using `SHGetFolderPath` and you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: **No, you can't** get the path to the bat that invoked the application.

According to the comments you are on a wrong track to achieve your goal (not clearly defined anyway).

Comment: Why not GetCurrentDir? That seems to work very well for me.

Comment: Because GetCurrentDir returns... the current dir which is **NOT** always the path to the bat that invoked the application. This has been discussed in the comments under your question. If there is something you don't understand, you **have to** open a new question. StackOverflow **do not allow** a chat discussion: It is a question and answer site.

Comment: @RaelB Because the initial working directory can be set when starting a process/app.